# WinAppDriver does not detect controls/component in LabVIEW executable

Tags: windows, element, labview, winappdriver, inspect.exe

I am using WinAppDriver to automate my LabVIEW app UI testing. Inspect.exe can detect top level of active window but couldn't locate element inside the window.
So I couldn't get the text inside the window. Does anyone know how I could get the text?

Thanks!
Mary

Comment: As WinAppDriver states, "This service supports testing Universal Windows Platform (UWP), Windows Forms (WinForms), Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF), and Classic Windows (Win32) apps on Windows 10 PCs.". So maybe LabVIEW executables are not so much supported by this tool...

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, standard UI automation tools do not work with programs written in LabVIEW. However, there are alternative solutions such as [LabVIEW UI Automation Tool](http://forums.ni.com/t5/NI-Labs-Toolkits/LabVIEW-UI-Automation-Tool/ta-p/3521765). You should check this out, it may be helpful for you.